# Background animation doesn't work (CSS, SCSS)

Tags: html, css, sass

I would like my background to appear slowly and gradually and I thought it would be fairly easy but I can't. Any suggestions? Can I only do it with html, CSS and SCSS (not a proficient user of the latter yet).

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1001682/pexels-photo-1001682.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation-name: b-anime;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transition-property: background;
  @keyframes b-anime {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    25% {
      opacity: 0.25;
    }
    50% {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
    75% {
      opacity: 0.75;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>icy-blues</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website1.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width>
        <meta name=" description " content="xx ">
        <meta name="keywords " content="stuff ">
        <meta name="author " content="Ray ">
    </head>

     <body>



     </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: make the keyframe outside the body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, your `keyframes` definition has to be outside of your `body` styling.
Then, it's not possible in this case, to use `opacity` for `background-image` transparency, [take a look at a opacity documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity).

But you could set the transparent effect for a `::after` element, and animate this.

You could do it this way:

```css
body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1001682/pexels-photo-1001682.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: b-anime;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    transition-property: background;
  }

@keyframes b-anime {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    25% {
      opacity: 0.25;
    }
    50% {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
    75% {
      opacity: 0.75;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```